# Python threading: wait for thread to stop then execute function

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I'm trying to run a function after my thread has completed but the function is not called. Code structure:

```
class():

    def functiontocall()  # uses data calculated in thread for plotting. only works when thread is complete
        do something with self.A

    def watchthread():
        thread()
        functiontocall()
        # since this function depends on variable A, it throws an error.
        # I tried: if thread.join == True: functiontocall but this did not call the function.

    def thread():
        def run():
            pythoncom.CoInitialize()
            --- do stuff --
            for i in 1000:
                thousands of calculations while updating state in GUI ---
            A = result
            self.A = A
        thread = threading.Thread(target=run)
        thread.start()
```

note: i removed 'self' for simplicity.

thread.join should tell me when the thread has finished but for some reason i still cant run the functiontocall.

Is this a bad way of organizing threads in general?

Edit: I can call the function after the thread is finished but I cannot access variables when the thread is running. e.g. 0-100% progress for a progress bar in my GUI. when I use:

```
def watchthread():
    thread()
    thread.join()
    functiontocall()
```

I cannot update the status of the thread in my GUI. It just waits until the calculations are finished then runs functiontocall().

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using threads, once the thread had started Python will move onto the next thing, it will not wait for the thread to finish unless you've asked it to.

With your code, if you want to wait for the thread function to finish before moving on then it doesn't sound like you need threading, a normal function would run, complete, and then Python will move onto running functiontocall()

If there's a reason you need to use threads which isn't coming across in the example then I would suggest using a thread.join()

```
threads = []  # list to hold threads if you have more than one
t = threading.Thread(target=run)
threads.append(t)

for thread in threads:  # wait for all threads to finish
    thread.join() 

functiontocall()  # will only run after all threads are done
```

Again, I'd suggest relooking at whether threads is what you need to use here as it doesn't seem apparent.

To update this answer based on the new information, this may be the way you want to have a variable be accessible. In this case the threads would all update your class variable A, your GUI update function also reads this periodically and updates your GUI.

```
class ThisClass():

    def __init__(self):
        self.A = 0

    def function_to_call(self):
        while self.A != 100:  # assuming this is a progress bar to 100%
            # update in GUI

    def run(self):
        # does calculations
        with lock: # to prevent issues with threads accessing variable at the same time
            self.A += calculations

    def progress(self):
        threads = []  # list to hold threads if you have more than one
        t = threading.Thread(target=run)
        threads.append(t)

        f = threading.Thread(target=self.function_to_call)
        threads.append(f)

        for thread in threads:
            thread.start()

        for thread in threads:  # wait for all threads to finish
            thread.join()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need threading because I'm running multiple calculations and I'm updating progress in a GUI. I have updated my question.

Comment: You can't really return values from threads, however since you're using a class why not try storing the value in a variable which then each thread could update?

For example self.A = None 
Each thread can then do 
    with lock:
        self.A = x

Comment: sorry. yes I used return to simplify. I do assign variables.

Comment: hopefully, the question makes more sense now?

Comment: Updated my answer to better show this. The threads can update your class variable which your GUI update function then reads and updates within the GUI

Comment: I'm not sure if this is adaptable to my code because I have multiple variables. I only need one thread. The thread performs calculations and updates GUI status. I then use some of the variables to plot data using the functiontocall() method. Your answer seems to be a bit excessive for my needs.

Comment: If you only need one thread then it doesn't sound like you need to be using threads. If your calculations need to be performed within the same function then why not just call another function within that thread which updates the GUI and pass the variable to it?

Comment: The reason i need a thread is because I have a for loop. I update the status of the GUI using variables calculated in this for loop. If i didn't have a thread, the method would just calculate and wait. I wouldn't get any update.

Comment: That's why I'm suggesting you perform the update from within the loop which is currently your thread loop. So when your current thread loop finishes one of it's caculations, you then call the GUI update function with whatever the result is